# Swift reduce function issue

Tags: arrays, swift

I have one array of heart rate. All I want is get an average of last 5 mins heart rate. (Array contains more than last hour heart rate).

```
class HeartRate
{
    var hr = 0
    var date : Date?
}

var arrHeartRate = [HeartRate]()
let minDate = Date().addingTimeInterval(-300) //get 5min before time
var avgHR = self.arrHeartRate.filter { (Item) -> Bool in
                return Item.date! > minDate
            }.reduce(0) { (res, item) -> Result<Any, <#Error: Error#>> in
                return res
            }
```

Comment: Please add your array in Question

Comment: @AshokLondhe done

Comment: Your problem is solved or you updated Question. i want your sample heart rate array so that i will try to solve your problem.

Comment: @AshokLondhe this is var arrHeartRate = [HeartRate]() my array and heart rate class is already given above. it include 2 variables (hr and date)

Comment: You are right but i am expecting sample data into that array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is some code for you, which is an aggregation of different stackoverflow answers.

```
class HeartRate
{
    var hr = 0
    var date: Date?
}

extension Collection where Iterator.Element == HeartRate, Index == Int {
    /// Returns the average of all elements in the array
    var average: Double {
        return isEmpty ? 0 : Double(reduce(0) { $0 + $1.hr }) / Double(endIndex-startIndex)
    }
}

var arrHeartRate = [HeartRate(), HeartRate()]
let minDate = Date().addingTimeInterval(-300) //get 5min before time
let rateInLast5Min = arrHeartRate.filter {
    guard let date = $0.date else { return false }
    return date > minDate
}
var avgHR = rateInLast5Min.average
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do filter and reduce in two steps. First, get an array of heart rate within the time frame

```
let filtered = arrHeartRate.filter{$0.date ?? Date() > minDate}
```

Or some tweak to exclude nil date from the filtered array

```
let filtered = arrHeartRate.filter{$0.date ?? Date().addingTimeInterval(-500) > minDate}
```

Then calculate average and return

```
return Double(filtered.reduce(0){$0 + $1.hr}) / Double(filtered.count)
```

Comment: This answer is already posted by TomCobo But just changed name of variable. the result of both the answers is same

Comment: showing issue like.  Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Comment: @TejasArdeshna On which line does the issue happen?

Comment: {$0.hr + $1.hr}

Comment: @TejasArdeshna Oops, that's a mistake. Fixed

Comment: Force unwrapping the `date` is a major issue in your suggested code, since the `date` is an optional, force unwrapping it will lead to crashes. Copy/Paste code :)

Comment: @OlegDanu Sure. Though OP wants two line solution.

Comment: @TejasArdeshna Updated this two line solution with nil date handling, if you still need it

Comment: with this condition ´?? Date() ´ all the heartRates will be included

Comment: @TomCobo No. That is just a default for a nil date. You can also tweak the code to exclude nil date

Answer (score 1):

I haven't run it but with some adjustments should be what you are looking for

```
    let rateInLast5Min = arrHeartRate.filter({ 0$.date! > minDate  })
let hours = rateInLast5Min.map{ return $0.hr }.reduce(0, +)
let average = Double(hours)/Double(rateInLast5Min.count)
```

Comment: Showing error. Type of expression is ambiguous without more context